# Composer does not detect php7 instead it uses 5.6. How can I set the CLI to use php7

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, php-7

Here when I execute `php -v` , it says it has php7

[image]

but when I try to execute `composer update`

the response it

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - This package requires php >=7.0.0 but your PHP version (5.6.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

How can I fix this?
NOTE : I'm not allowed to uninstall previous version of php

Here is the composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^v1",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/misc.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

I already tried

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

but I still I get another error, which is again related to the above problem.

Comment: show us `composer.json` file

Comment: - delete previous entry of php path from environment variable and give php7 path, and also stop xampp or wamp server that is using php5.6

Comment: Try deleting your `composer.lock` file and running `composer update` again

Comment: @MuhammadSadiq : I'm not allowed to remove previous version of php

Comment: @SapneshNaik : tried that now, same result

Comment: Delete environment variable of php version 5.6.33 and give the path of your latest php version eg- `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the question you already have both the versions of PHP on your system, As Laravel uses the cli version you need to enable 7.X and disable 5.X.

You can achieve that by below commands

```
$ sudo a2dismod php5.6 // disable the loaded version
$ sudo a2enmod php7.0 // enable the desired version
$ sudo service apache2 restart // restart apache to get it in action
```

For More information
You can install different version of PHP using the below commands

For Apache

```
$ sudo apt install php5.6   [PHP 5.6]
$ sudo apt install php7.0   [PHP 7.0]
$ sudo apt install php7.1   [PHP 7.1]
```

For Ngix

```
$ sudo apt install php5.6-fpm   [PHP 5.6]
$ sudo apt install php7.0-fpm   [PHP 7.0]
$ sudo apt install php7.1-fpm   [PHP 7.1]
```

To install any PHP modules, simply specify the PHP version and use the auto-completion functionality to view all modules as follows.

```
------------ press Tab key for auto-completion ------------ 
$ sudo apt install php5.6 
$ sudo apt install php7.0 
$ sudo apt install php7.1
```

Now you can install most required PHP modules as per your requirements.

```
------------ Install PHP Modules ------------
$ sudo apt install php5.6-cli php5.6-xml php5.6-mysql 
$ sudo apt install php7.0-cli php7.0-xml php7.0-mysql 
$ sudo apt install php7.1-cli php7.1-xml php7.1-mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

i had same issue and solved it by changing path under system variables.

- right click on my computer and click properties
- click advanced system settings on the left side menu
- make sure the advance tap menu is selected
- click on environment variables (buttom right)
- click on path under system variables panel
- click on edit
- locate php installed path (eg. C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.x.x)
- click edit and rename to your disired php version (eg. C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.5)
- click ok to save

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run composer with a different PHP version, try calling it using `php $(which composer) update`. You can exchange the path to the PHP cli now freely

Answer (score 0):

Check where your composer executable is located (using which) and check the first line (shebang). I guess this still points to old php version.

Answer (score 0):

Install via  this `sudo apt install php7.1 php7.1-fpm`  and recheck again and post the result.

Answer (score 0):

I use `phpbrew` for multi PHP versions. In my case this command fixed the issue with `composer` using wrong PHP version:

```
phpbrew app get composer
```