# Composer detects 5.6 instead of 7.1 when installing vendor

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, composer-php

I have installed xampp with different php versions of php (5.6 and 7.1) on my C:

when im trying to composer install for the project to have a vendor folder

it reads the php version  of 5.6 instead of the 7.1 windows

I tried searching 
and i saw one changing on environmental variable but i cant see the path for php versions

i also try [Composer does not detect php7 instead it uses 5.6. How can I set the CLI to use php7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535450/composer-does-not-detect-php7-instead-it-uses-5-6-how-can-i-set-the-cli-to-use)
but im using git bash not sudo (because ihave Wiondows as OS)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you type `where php` to your Command Prompt and tell us the output.

Comment: okay sir sorry for that

Comment: /c/xampp/php/php
but i need it to read the path of /c/xampp7.2/php/php

Comment: Are you sure the path to PHP doesn't present inside the "Environmental Variable" string? can you post it here?

Comment: yes sir  , ive posted a screenshot of it

Comment: The path string is really long, the screenshot doesn't show all. I believe the path to PHP is added at the end of the string.

Comment: sorry sir, ive edited it

Comment: As I guess your xampp is using php 5.6. Try to upgrade your xampp version.

Comment: @ShehanDhaleesha i have 2 xampp with different versions

Comment: Could you run `echo $PATH` inside your mingw window and check if it matches the Path environment variable from your screenshot?

Comment: @CarloE.Barrogo Yeah that's the problem. You have to remove old php and set the path variable to new php